# Set min-width css property to `max-content` after calculating/doing overflow wraps?

Tags: html, css

Well for a flex box (or grid) I wish to make sure that the content always fits inside a grid. However the grid should shrink if it can. So the grid is defined as:

```
.grid: {
    gridTemplateColumns: 'max-content 1fr',
    border-top-color: black;
    border-top-width: 1;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-left-color: black;
    border-left-width: 1;
    border-left-style: solid;
}
.grid-cell: {
    border-bottom-color: black;
    border-bottom-width: 1;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-right-color: black;
    border-right-width: 1;
    border-right-style: solid;
}
.rank: {
    grid-column: 1
.team: {
    min-width: "max-content";
    overflow-content: "break-words";
    gridColumn: 2;
}


<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-cell rank">rank</div>
    <div class="grid-cell team">team</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">generated column 1</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">generated column 2</div>

    <div class="grid-cell rank">1</div>
    <div class="grid-cell team">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">Values in column 1</div>
    <div class="grid-cell">Values in column 2</div>
</div>
```

However this function will stop "shrinking" the moment the width of the grid becomes the size of the total string. Even though the string could shrink further by wrapping the words.

I could remove the min-width. However this could cause the grid to shrink even "below" the maximum word size, and thus make cells overlap.

Can it be made so that a div has a minimum width that is equal to the maximum word, and it wraps words?

Comment: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hrcbyqaf/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You have quite some typo/syntax errors. I have rectified it and make a grid that might be your expected output.

```css
.grid { /* remove colon */
  display: grid; /* Add display grid */
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr; /* gridTemplateColumns to grid-template-columns */
  border-top-color: black;
  border-top-width: 1;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-left-color: black;
  border-left-width: 1;
  border-left-style: solid;
}

.grid-cell { /* remove colon */
  border-bottom-color: black;
  border-bottom-width: 1;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-right-color: black;
  border-right-width: 1;
  border-right-style: solid;
}

.rank { /* remove colon */
  grid-column: 1; /* Add semicolon */
} /* close parenthesis */

.team { /* remove colon */
  /*min-width: "max-content";
  overflow-wrap: "break-word"; *//* overflow-content to overflow-wrap */
  grid-column: 2; /* gridColumn to grid-column*/
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-cell rank">rank</div>
  <div class="grid-cell team">team</div>
  <div class="grid-cell">generated column 1</div>
  <div class="grid-cell">generated column 2</div>

  <div class="grid-cell rank">1</div>
  <div class="grid-cell team">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="grid-cell">Values in column 1</div>
  <div class="grid-cell">Values in column 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The typos are from the manual conversion from sass (codebase) to css (topic here). Sorry about that.

Comment: @paul23 FYI. There is an online (SCSS to CSS compiler)[https://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/]. I hope it will help.